# How can i convert a string to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.ITableEntity?

Tags: c#, windows, azure, azure-table-storage

Hi thanks in advance for all the help!
I'm having a problem updating my azure table and i'm not sure what to do
what im doing:
1.Parsing a json to a var
2.creating an instance of that var with another e.g. test = parsedJson.latest;
3. using that var (auto assigned string) with a table operation to insert or replace a table entity. The code used is below:

```
var o365Subnet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConvertJson>(o365Latest);

var o365Final = o365Subnet.latest;

TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(o365Subnet.latest);
```

Response: Argument 1: Cannot convert 'string' to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.ITableEntity'

Comment: You must have an object that implements this ITableEntity interface, otherwise you won’t be able to perform this insert or merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TableOperation.insertOrMerge(TableEntity entity) Method, the object instance implementing `TableEntity` to associate with the operation.

First, you need have a `TableEntity` like below:

```
public class DashboardApple : TableEntity
{
    public string Latest{ get; set; }
    public int ApplesCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then instantiate the table entity.

```
var dashboardApple = new DashboardApple
{
    PartitionKey = "myPartition",
    RowKey = "myRow",
    Latest= "GoldenDelicious",
    ApplesCount = 5
};
```

Finally, send the tableentity to `InsertOrMerge`.

```
 TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(dashboardApple);
```

According to your situation, you can set `Latest= o365Subnet.latest;`

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/10/19/azure-table-storage-little-gem-insertormerge/).

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this! really helped me out a lot!